# simplexml_load_file not working with larger xml

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess

I have to write a script which reads from a xml file...for this I have used simplexml_load_file. Below is the code which I have written

```
try
{

$xml=simplexml_load_file("top.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $items) { 
    echo $items->title . ", "; 
    echo $items->brand . ", "; 
} 
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e;

}
```

But its only returns me

> Error: Cannot create object

So I did some research on this and found that when I am trying this code with a smaller size of xml file it works but while trying with a larger one (55,094kb)...it fails to work. Is there any way to manage this size issue.

Comment: what does `file_exists("top.xml")`give you?

Comment: @michi...try
{
    fileexists("topGM.xml");
  
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e;
    
}  gives me 500 Internal server Error

Comment: I suggest you remove the XML tag from the question. Seems no XML problem, but how to retrieve a file from an URI.

Comment: Where did you find the information that "php_value allow_url_fopen On" would work in your .htaccess? Please see the link I closed your question against as duplicate, it says that it won't work that way (you can also double check with the PHP manual which docuemnts with each ini-setting as well where it can (and can not) be changed).

Comment: @hakre...I have edited the question...

Comment: @michi...its the issue with larger xml files...I just found out.

Comment: 55,094 kb is not large. That's a 55 mb file, that size is normally no problem at all for simplexml. Do not only refer to your own error message here (the one you create in your script by die-ing). Instead do proper return value checking first and process the errors php/libxml was giving opening and parsing the XML document.

Comment: @hakre...I have resolved the issue...I used XMLReader() to resolve this